# Monitors with different physical sizes

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10

I have two monitors on my windows 10 machine:

Monitor 1 (Main): 1680x1050 Samsung T220 (22")

Monitor 2: 1920x1080 Dell E2211H

The physical height of these two monitors is several inches different (the Samsung is taller).

I am attempting to set up the monitor positioning in Windows, so that the top of the Dell is in line with the position on the Samsung to comes up to.

Unfortunately, the display settings screen sees the Dell as physically taller than the Samsung.

[image: Display Settings]

Is there a way to tell Windows 10 that the secondary monitor is wider, but not as tall?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Windows knows nothing about the physical screen, only the resolution.  The customization screen is an abstraction (positioning refers to which screen is on the left).  It uses all of the real estate on each screen.  If you want the tops of the screens to line up, you'll need to put the shorter screen on top of a book.

Comment: @fixer1234 My issue is that windows thinks the second monitor is taller than #1, but its not. As it is, there's no way the two items will line up properly. When I mouse off one monitor and onto the other, the mouse jumps up or down the screen.

Comment: The Samsung is physically taller but lower vertical resolution.  That's a tough one and I don't think there's a nice solution.  If the resolution was higher, you could pursue using a lower resolution without interpolation (cropping the unused part of the screen), and then physically aligning the tops of the images.  Starting with a lower resolution, you would lose valuable screen real estate.  Even if you aligned the tops, nothing below that will line up.  To do well what you want will really require another monitor with similar characteristics (height and resolution).

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be the case. I found an older thread that said similar. Was hoping win10 was a little better at dealing with it.

Comment: No matter how good Windows 10 is, you're dealing with laws of nature.  You can't beat Mother Nature.  :-)