# Physical size of screen in Windows 7 display settings

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, display-settings

I'm using Windows 7 on a laptop with a pretty small 1920x1080 screen and an external 1920x1200 screen that is much bigger physically.

No matter how I set the position of the external screen relative to the internal screen in `Display->Screen Resolution`, there's always a point where horizontal lines across displays don't line up, because Windows assumes the pixels to be the same physical size on both displays.

Can I either resize the monitor in the system settings or use a third party program to handle the two monitors better? Or is this impossible because a window that's half on one, half on the other screen would have conflicting information about resolution? If that's the case, I would also accept a solution where only the mouse movement across screen scales properly A difficulty with that might be different mouse sensitivity between screens, but that's already not very consistent.

I could of course just reduce the screen resolution of the internal monitor, but that... well, would reduce the resolution. I don't want that.

There is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/958135/monitors-with-different-physical-sizes), but I'm not sure if the asker means the same thing. I think he has a monitor with non-square pixels. I'm only concerned with the physical height.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1 and thereafter, you can change the "per display dpi scaling" as detailed https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements/ here. However, since it is a new feature added in Windows 8.1, the feature is not available in Windows 7. Consider upgrading the windows version.

Comment: Since it's a work PC, that's not possible. But your answer might still help people searching for something similar.

Comment: Wait, no, it doesn't actually help. That's scaling of UI elements, which means that I would lose space on the smaller display. As I said, I don't want that. It might be impossible to do what I want, but as I said, then I would also accept a solution that only scales the cursor position correctly.

Comment: You can keep the same dpi on the smaller display and then change the dpi of the larger display. However I am not too sure about its effect on cursor. @Fabian

Comment: But I can only increase the DPI, not reduce. 100% is the minimum.

Comment: humm... it is possible to reduce the meaning of 100% dpi via regedit by changing the value of logpixels in Win7, but it doesn't work in win8.1/10 so it would not be possible to use together with this method.

Comment: That's a shame. Maybe there's a third party program that can port back this feature to Windows 7? Or just one that takes control over the mouse and moves it up or down a bit whenever I move it to the other screen.